# NSInternalInconsistencyException uncaught exception while Sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I think My openDB method is creating this error --- "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Database failesad to open'".

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm running xcode 4.6

```
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];  
}

-(void) openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failesad to open");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you written code to copy your database from app's bundle to device's directory ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm a novice.

Comment: Where is your sqlite database located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line in you code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

and compare it with this one

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

The reason is that you use wrong `NSSerachPathForDirectory` in you `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` method

Answer (score 0):

The above was from a youtube tutorial i was following. One of the users posted this code which makes it work! But **i'm not sure why it is so**...

```
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject]; NSString* databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"]; return databasePath;
```

can anyone explain this?